# Stencil bundle throwing error that templates are missing

Tags: bigcommerce

When I run `stencil bundle` for my theme, I get the following error output:

```
failed  -- The following template(s) are/is missing:
components/common/forms
components/common/icons
```

These templates don't exist. They are directories. Why would I be receiving this error?

I had to add empty files to my theme in order to work around this. I added the following two blank files:

```
templates/components/common/forms.html
templates/components/common/icons.html
```

That fixed the problem, but seems like that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: have you tested bundling cornerstone and see if it throws the same error?

Comment: I have, and I do not see the error. I can't think of anything in my theme that would cause this to happen. I'm not referencing those components anywhere different from cornerstone.

Comment: Do you have any content or templates inside those directories for your own theme?

Comment: The `forms` directory contains exactly the same files as the cornerstone theme, and I have not made any changes to any of them. The `icons` directory only contains the `icon-defs.html` file, just like cornerstone. The only difference here is I have added some icons myself via the `grunt svgstore` task.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that if I ever have a file open in a directory that is included somewhere in a `dynamicComponent` helper call, I get an error that a template file is missing and the missing files is the swp file created by VIM because the file is currently loaded. It's like stencil is trying to load the swap file or something like that. I'm not sure if it's related, but the error is similar, os just thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the node version issue. Please install the latest version of node. I was working on node version (4.6.1) so I have uninstalled it and install latest then it's working.